# Python 2.7 Cx_Freeze: ImportError: No module named __startup__

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7, cx-freeze

I am trying to compile a hello world program in Python into a stand-alone binary/package on Linux using cx_Freeze. When cx_Freeze is run, it completes without an error but when I attempt to run the generated executable, I am given the error:

```
ImportError: No module named __startup__
```

My setup.py file is:

```
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

# Dependencies are automatically detected, but it might need
# fine tuning.
buildOptions = dict(packages = [], excludes = [])

base = 'Console'

executables = [
    Executable('test.py', base=base)
]

setup(name='test',
      version = '1.0',
      description = '',
      options = dict(build_exe = buildOptions),
      executables = executables)
```

And it is run as such:

```
python setup.py build
```

I am confused as to why this is happening. If the ImportError was for a library, I would understand - but `__startup__` is unfamiliar to me.

Thanks.

Comment: \__startup__ is the module that cx_Freeze uses to start up the application. Can you provide the contents of the test.py that you are using? Are you able to use the simple example in the cx_Freeze distribution? Or do you get the same error there?

Comment: Possibly related [bug on `cx_freeze` bug tracker](https://github.com/anthony-tuininga/cx_Freeze/issues/209). Any chance you're running in a virtual environment?

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem with cx_Freeze 5.0.0. I was able to fix this after downgrading cx_freeze to 4.3.4. Other versions may also work.

Comment: I am finding cx_freeze 5.0.1 very buggy or incompatible with 4.3.4

Answer (score -3):

I encountered the same problem.For your goals, you can try pinstaller.'hello world' accurately compile. But the question remains open, how to conquer this bug

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Your answer does not carry too much value for the raised question, and it does not solve the reported bug/problem. For the future, here is some information, how to crack a awesome answer on Stack Overflow: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer